# Qt event filter hides the widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qobject

I have a parent widget inside which I have to place a custom widget (say a `QFrame`). Inside that custom widget, I have to place a number of child widgets (derived from `QPushButton`). I want the child widgets to have a certain background under normal circumstances, and another one when hovered upon. This is my code:

```
//parent widget code, where the QFrame derived widget is initialized
QFrameDerivedWidget *qFrameWidget = new QFrameDerivedWidget(this, someString);
```

This is the `QFrameDerivedWidget` header file:

```
//QFrameDerivedWidget header file
class QFrameDerivedWidget: public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QFrameDerivedWidget(QWidget *aParent,
                         std::string someValue);
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
}
```

This is the `QFrameDerivedWidget` implementation file, the `ChildWidget` class is defined and declared inline:

```
class ChildWidget: public QPushButton
{
Q_Object
public:
    ChildWidget(std::string aText, QWidget *aParent);

};

ChildWidget::ChildWidget(std::string aText, QWidget *aParent):
                               QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(aText),aParent)
{
    this->setFixedHeight(30);
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    this->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    /* ---other custom styling--- */
}

bool QFrameDerivedWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    // this never prints out anything, even though it should for any mouseenter, mouseleave, click, etc event on it
    qDebug() << obj->metaObject()->className() << endl;

    if (obj->metaObject()->className() == "ChildWidget")
    {
        //including this line throws a 'missing QObject missing macro error' as well
        ChildWidget *option = qobject_cast<ChildWidget* >(obj);
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
        {
            option->setStyleSheet("---");

        }
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Leave)
        {
            option->setStyleSheet("---");
        }
        return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
    else
    {
        // pass the event on to the parent class
        return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}

QFrameDerivedWidget::QFrameDerivedWidget(QWidget *aParent,
                     std::string someVal): fParent(aParent)
{
    initUI();
}

QFrameDerivedWidget::initUI()
{
    this->setParent(fParent);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    QWidget *dd = new QWidget(this);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    dd->setLayout(layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < fValues.size(); i++)
    {
        ChildWidget *button = new ChildWidget(fValues[i],dd);
        button->addEventFilter(this);
        layout->addWidget(button);
    }
}
```

The idea is, whenever I hover over the `QFrameDerivedWidget` and enter any `ChildWidget`, its background color should change. Additionally, I have set a `qDebug()` statement inside the `eventFilter`. It is currently not working, the `ChildWidget` buttons are not visible, but they are there, for the cursor turns pointer when I hover over where they are supposed to be.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I make it work?

Comment: `obj->metaObject()->className() == "ChildWidget"` may be replaced with `qobject_cast<ChildWidget *>(obj) != nullptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forget to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in `ChildWidget` declaration
2. You need to track mouse (`setMouseTracking(true)`)
3. You need to set `setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover)` to your widget
4. Be sure that you really need to `return true;` in your event filter, instead of returning `QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);`. You don't need to filter out hover events.

Comment: `ChildWidget` is already derived from `QPushButton`, which contains the macro in-built. Why do I need to do it again? And I have tried doing that, I still get the error..

Comment: @Cupidvogel you may read Qt documentation about `Q_OBJECT` macro. And I think that you have not error, but warning. I couldn't help you without  SSCCE.

Comment: Sure. It will be nice, if your provide full headers + show code, how you install event filter.

Comment: Well, I moved the inline definition of `ChildWidget` to a new class and implementation file, added the `QObject` macro, and set mouse tracking to true for both `ChildWidget` and `QFrameDerivedWidget`. It is still not working, although the `QObject macro needed ` error is not coming. But the hover event color change, or the normal `qDebug()` which should work for any event, are not working.

Comment: I forgot one thing, I have now added `button->installEventFilter(this)` in the for loop where I created the `ChildWidget` buttons in a fell swoop. Now the problem is that the buttons are not visible at all. When I hover over the `QFrameDerivedWidget` where the `ChildWidget` buttons are supposed to be, I see the cursor turning pointer (I used `setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor)` for them,  but the buttons are not visible. I have faced this issue before in another scenario as well. How do I fix this?

Comment: You may update your question with related changes in code. It is hard to extract information from comments.

Comment: Nothing to review. You still fixed nothing from my recomentations.

Comment: Done them. Please see edit. I now am just unable to view the child widgets, even though they are present..

Comment: What should I do instead of the `return true` in the `if` part of the `eventFilter`?

Comment: Did that. Please see edited code. Still not working, that is, the `ChildWidget`s are not visible, although they are there, the cursor turns pointer on hovering over their supposed position. I inserted some `qDebug()` statements inside `if (obj->metaObject()->className() == "ChildWidget")`, it doesn't work. I also tried `qobject_cast<ChildWidget *>(obj) != nullptr`, same result. Mind you, this invisibility problem came only after I added this line: `button->installEventFilter(this);`..

Comment: You have a lot of typo. If you need any help - please, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can fix typos myself, I don't need a user guide to know that. Thanks for your help and the downvote.

Comment: 1 question -> 1 answer. But we can't go this way, because you can't make your question readable.

Comment: Okay, at least tell me what are the typos. As far as I can tell, I have made all the fixes you suggested, and have aded them in the code. Where are you seeing the typos?

Comment: Instead of return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event); do return QFrame::eventFilter(obj, event);